# Does ActiveMQ Artemis management API handle the whole cluster?

Tags: activemq-artemis

If you have ActiveMQ Artemis cluster, does the management API manage the whole cluster or just single instance? E.g. if you add a users, queues, addresses, security settings etc., are those added to all servers in the cluster or just the server you're connected to? Or can the management of the whole cluster from a single server instance be achieved with some additional configuration?

Comment: Are you asking about a cluster of _active_ brokers or an HA pair of brokers (one of which is active and the other is passive)?

Comment: I guess active brokers...? I mean configuration that upscales client connections. From what I've read I've understood that in HA the failover servers stay inactive and don't handle client connections when the active server is online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis management API manages single instance.